# Como mando un array en PDO para usarlo en un {html_options} de smarty

Tags: php, base-de-datos, pdo

Estoy actualizando una sección que usa mysql a **PDO** para desplegar en un **{html_options}** de **Smarty**, y algo que funciona bien en mysql no se cómo lograrlo con PDO

Este es el código original que funciona bien actualmente:

```
//Mando estados
$q="SELECT id, estado FROM estados";
$data=$db->execute($q);
$idEstados=array();
$estados=array();
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($data);$i++) {
    array_push($idEstados,$data[$i]->id);
    array_push($estados,$data[$i]->estado);
}
$smarty->assign('idEstados',$idEstados);
$smarty->assign('estados',$estados);
```

Luego en el .tpl todo se muestra correctamente, incluyendo "selected" que es el me importa más, si no, haría un {foreach} para desplegar los estados.

```
<select name="destino_idEstado" class="form-control">
    <option>Seleccione un Estado</option>   
    {html_options output="$estado" values="$idEstado" selected=$data->idEstado}
</select>
```

Lo que estoy haciendo con PDO funciona bien si hago un {foreach}, pero necesito usar el "selected" y me es más fácil hacerlo con el {html_options} de smarty, pero no se cómo enviar el array desde PDO para que funcione.

```
$sql1="SELECT id,estado FROM testados";

$stmt = $dba->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt->execute(); 

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $idEstado = $row['id'];
    $estado = $row['estado'];

    $smarty->assign('idEstado', $idEstado);
    $smarty->assign('estado',$estado);
}
```

De esta forma NO marca error, sólo no despliega el  correspondiente.

¿Alguien podría orientarme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás reasignando las variables de php y de smarty en cada iteración del bucle, por lo que sólo retendrán la última iteración.

Transformando lo segundo para que se comporte como en tu primer ejemplo,  lo siguiente debiera funcionar.

```
$sql1="SELECT id,estado FROM estados";

$stmt = $dba->prepare($sql1); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$idEstados=array();
$estados=array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    array_push($idEstados,$row['id']);
    array_push($estados,$row['estado']);

}

$smarty->assign('idEstados', $idEstados);
$smarty->assign('estados',$estados);
```

Comment: Gracias amenadiel, probé tu sugerencia y resultó el mismo espacio en blanco; luego las llamé en el .tpl con {$estados} y {$idEstados} y el resultado fue: Array Array. Luego intenté con un echo, y el resultado fue Array Array<br><!DOCTYPE html>...

Comment: Pero, en el primer caso, el que sí funciona, en tu .tpl tienes las variables en plural, verdad?

Comment: Sí, así lo tengo en el .tpl {html_options output=$estados values=$idEstados selected=$destino.idEstado}

Comment: hay alguna parte en donde estés asignando el valor de $data a la plantilla?

Comment: Ya no, es una plantilla nueva. En la anterior sí usaba $data

Comment: ¡Listo! tenía un error en mi sql, por eso no tenía buen resultado, ya lo corregí y tu recomendación funciona a la perfección. Gracias